# Listado de registros con Php MySql simplificado

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Estoy haciendo un sistema de partidos, donde en un formulario cargo todos los jugadores local, y los visitantes, cargo el resultado y eso inserto en la base de datos, el problema es el listado.
Aclaro: El id_juego lo hice para identificar el partido, ahi hay 4 id_juego 1 que significa que pertenece al mismo partidoo con 4 jugadores.
asi se inserta en la base de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando hago el listado de partido viene todos los registros, y se mescla todo, me gustaria traer solo 1 registro por ejemplo la fecha del partido por decir, y cuando clik en la fecha del partido en otra pagina muestro todos los jugadores que jugaron ese partido.

No se como hacerlo, para crear un registro por partido, asi hago el listado de ese registro y cuando click en un registro me muestre en otra pagina todos los jugadores que jugaron ese partido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas una consulta que te de solo un resultado por partido,y al hacer "click" como dices (eso ya lo harás con javascript), necesitarás otra consulta (obviamente) con el "id_juego" específico.

Supongamos que tu tabla se llama **juegos**.

La consulta que nos muestras responde a una consulta tipo:

```
SELECT *
FROM juegos
```

Por lo que expones, no quieres que salgan 4 resultados por cada id_partido, si no que solo quieres uno y recibir la fecha. Para eso tenemos el DISTINCT o incluso el GROUP BY

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_juego, fecha_id
FROM juegos
```

También lo conseguirías haciendo:

```
SELECT fecha_id
FROM juegos
GROUP BY id_juego
```

Sea como sea como decidas hacerlo, al "hacer click" como dices, lanzarás otra petición al servidor, pidiendo todos los datos del partido que te interesa. (que tendras el `id_juego`en questión)

Así que sería un:

```
SELECT *
FROM juegos
WHERE id_juego = xxx

// xxx será el numero que tendras, el que te interesa. 
// Esta consulta te dará los 4 resultados (4 players) con toda la info.
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, @ferter3006, ahi me salio como queria, mil gracias.